# How do I position these three so that they are all horizontally next to each other?

Tags: math-mode

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

%Paragraph jumps and indentation
\setlength{\parindent}{1.27cm}


%Border
\usepackage[left=0.5in, right=0.5in, top=0.5in, bottom=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\raisebox{-0.8\headsep}{\thepage}} % lowering the right header
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

%Packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\usepackage{float}
%Images
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{chart}{tbph}{loc}
\floatname{chart}{Graph}



%Tables
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{caption}

%Equation numbering
\counterwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
   \Delta m_{\textnormal{exp}} &=\frac{m_{\textnormal{exp,max}}-m_{\textnormal{exp,min}}}{2}\\
   \Delta m_{\textnormal{exp}}&=\frac{\left(-5.684 \times 10^{-4}\right)-\left(-4.823 \times 10^{-4}\right)}{2}\\
   \Delta m_{\textnormal{exp}}&=-4.305\times10^{-5}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    \Delta y_{\textnormal{exp}} &=\frac{y_{\textnormal{exp,max}}-y_{\textnormal{exp,min}}}{2}\\
   \Delta m_{\textnormal{exp}}&=\frac{1.003-0.9800}{2}\\
   \Delta m_{\textnormal{exp}}&=0.0115
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    \Delta x_{\textnormal{exp}} &=\frac{x_{\textnormal{exp,min}}-y_{\textnormal{exp,max}}}{2}\\
   \Delta m_{\textnormal{exp}}&=\frac{2031.9\ldots -1764.6\ldots}{2}\\
   \Delta x_{\textnormal{exp}}&=133.6
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is use `aligned` environments in table. In equations are instead of `\textnormal{exp}` and `textnormal{max}` used math operators `\exp` and `\max` respectively. For `-4.823 \times 10^{-4}` and similar expression is rather used `siunitx` notation `\num{-5.684e-4}`:

With this changes the code become much shorter and more clear:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{nccmath}
    \counterwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\usepackage{hyperref}
    \urlstyle{same}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} X[1.2,c] X[0.9,c] X[0.9,c] @{}} }
    \begin{aligned}
\Delta m_{\exp} & = \mfrac{m_{\exp,\max} - m_{\exp,\min}}{2}    \\
\Delta m_{\exp} & = \mfrac{(\num{-5.684e-4}) - (\num{-4.823e-4})}{2}    \\
\Delta m_{\exp} &=-4.305\times10^{-5}
    \end{aligned}           
    &    \begin{aligned}
    \Delta y_{\exp} & = \mfrac{y_{\exp,\max} - y_{\exp,\min}}{2}    \\
    \Delta m_{\exp} & = \mfrac{1.003 - 0.9800}{2}   \\
    \Delta m_{\exp} & = 0.0115
        \end{aligned}
        &    \begin{aligned}
        \Delta x_{\exp} & = \mfrac{x_{\exp,\min} - y_{\exp,\max}}{2}    \\
        \Delta m_{\exp} & = \mfrac{2031.9\ldots - 1764.6\ldots}{2}      \\
        \Delta x_{\exp} & = 133.6
            \end{aligned}
    \end{tblr}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you want?
I made the three equations fit textwidth using medium-sized fraction where necessary.
B.t.w., you don't have to load `colortbl`  if you load `xcolor` with option `table`, as the latter does it for you.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

    %Paragraph jumps and indentation
    \setlength{\parindent}{1.27cm}


    %Border
    \usepackage[left=0.5in, right=0.5in, top=0.5in, bottom=0.5in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[R]{\raisebox{-0.8\headsep}{\thepage}} % lowering the right header
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

    %Packages
    %\usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{nccmath, amsfonts}
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \captionsetup{justification=centering}
    \usepackage{float}
    %Images
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    \graphicspath{ {./images/} }
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage{float}
    \newfloat{chart}{tbph}{loc}
    \floatname{chart}{Graph}



    %Tables
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{tabu}
    \usepackage{caption}

    %Equation numbering
    \counterwithin{equation}{section}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \urlstyle{same}
    \usepackage{booktabs,array}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{makecell}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{adjustbox}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{align*}
       \Delta m_{\textnormal{exp}} &=\frac{m_{\textnormal{exp,max}}-m_{\textnormal{exp,min}}}{2}
        & \Delta y_{\textnormal{exp}} &=\frac{y_{\textnormal{exp,max}}-y_{\textnormal{exp,min}}}{2}
         & \Delta x_{\textnormal{exp}} &=\frac{x_{\textnormal{exp,min}}-y_{\textnormal{exp,max}}}{2}\\
       \Delta m_{\textnormal{exp}}&=\mfrac{\left(-5.684 \times 10^{-4}\right)-\left(-4.823 \times 10^{-4}\right)}{2} & \Delta m_{\textnormal{exp}}&=\frac{1.003-0.9800}{2} & \Delta m_{\textnormal{exp}}&=\frac{2031.9\ldots -1764.6\ldots}{2}\\
       \Delta m_{\textnormal{exp}}&=-4.305\times10^{-5} & \Delta m_{\textnormal{exp}}&=0.0115 &
       \Delta x_{\textnormal{exp}}&=133.6
    \end{align*}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the `\flalign*` environment.